# Расположение элементов - foreach

Tags: foreach

Как с помощью `foreach()` расположить элементы коллекции в 2 столбика? https://ravon.ru/dealer-list - примерно вот так.

```
<div class="dropdown-dealers" >
    @foreach (var item in Model)
    {
        <div class="dropdown-list">
            <div class="dropdown-name"><span class="region_name">@item.RegionName</span></div>
            <div class="dropdown-content">
                @foreach (var diler in item.Dealers)
                {
                    <p style="color:red;"> @diler.DealerName</p>
                }
            </div>
        </div>
    }
</div>
```

Comment: Какой язык? Коллекция как выглядит?

Comment: Уточните, пожалуйста, о каком языке идет речь, и что значит "расположить в 2 столбика"? Пример будет очень полезен.

Comment: Что за столбики? По каким критериям они располагаются в том или ином столбце? О каком ЯП идет речь?

Comment: @Michael похоже на C# Razor синтакс

Answer (score 2):

Предлагаю создать счётчик

```
int i=0;
foreach(var element in collection){
 if(i%2==0){
stolbik1.add(element);
}else{
stolbik2.add(element);
}
i++;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

не понятно, какой язык имеется в виду, но принцип простой - для каждого элемента берете его индекс, берете остаток от деления на 2, если 0 - кладете в один столбик, если 1 - то в другой.